# ACRA + NativeCrashHandler

Tags: android, crash, android-ndk, acra

I am building a native android application. To get crashes I am using ACRA 4.5 with Native-Crash-Handler as suggested on ACRA's Advanced usage page for catching the native crashes. It works fine when I run it in `SILENT` mode. But if I use `DIALOG` or `NOTIFICATION` mode, on a native crash, the app keeps on crashing with the same exception everytime I click the <kbd>OK</kbd> button and fall in an endless loop. Does it work for anybody or is it just a limitation here?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/SalomonBrys/Native-Crash-Handler

Have you noticed that the project is discontinued?

"Moreover, the use of this library usually makes matter worse when the app crashes inside a thread : The Android system tries to restart the faulting activity making the app having an infinite crash loop."

Comment: No I didnt notice and I did encounter the bug. :) Although, there is fix for that in API level >= 14 using the lifecycle callbacks, I eventually ended up NOT using the library at all.